# cant find Route when action has 2 params - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller named `Blog`.
I have an action like this:

```
[Route("{code:int}/{title?}")]
public virtual ActionResult Index(int code, string title)
{
    var postModel = _blogService.Get(code.ToUrlDecription());
    return View(postModel);
}
```

I entered these urls, but all of them returned not found:

- `localhost:7708/Blog/index/12/post-title`;
- `localhost:7708/Blog/index/12`;
- `localhost:7708/Blog/12/post-title`.

I tried to write a route like below, but the result was the same:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "showblogpost", url: "{controller}/{action}/{code}/{title}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "Blog",
        action = "Index",
        title = UrlParameter.Optional
    },
    namespaces:new string[] { "Web.Controllers" }
);
```

Comment: Why do you need that [Route] attribute on action?

Comment: I think maybe can do with `route attribute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing, you don't need to use both attribute `[Route]` on action and mapping route.

In your attribute `[Route]` you have specified only parameters, so route according to it should be **`localhost:7708/12`**
by route, specified in `MapRoute` it should be **`localhost:7708/showblogpost/12`**

What I suggest is - remove your attribute, name your route in `MapRoute` as you want to see in URL, and also you can remove "string title" parameter from action, as it's not used.